# How to get coordinates of point of intersection of two lines in Direct2D?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics

In my Win32 application I've painted (in runtime) two lines using `Direct2D`. I call `CompareWithGeometry` method and recognize that these lines are intersecting lines. But I don't know about coordinates of lines intersection point. How to get coordinates of point of intersection of two lines in `Direct2D`?